# C++, Cannot get protected abstract Class property

Tags: c++, abstract-class, getter-setter

H everyone,

I am creating a getter/setter of an extended Abstract Class, I do not understand why I am able to set the property value but not read it from the setter .

// Main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cat.h"
int main() {
  Cat* tom;
  tom->setName("TOM");
  std::cout << tom->getName() << std::endl; // Here I got error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
  return 0;
}
```

//Animal.h file

```
#ifndef CLASSES_ANIMAL
#define CLASSES_ANIMAL

#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Animal {
  protected:
    string name;
  public:
    virtual inline string getName() const = 0;
    virtual void setName() = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
};

#endif //CLASSES_ANIMAL
```

// In Cat.h

```
#ifndef CLASSES_CAT_H
#define CLASSES_CAT_H

#include <string>
#include "animal.h"

class Cat : protected Animal {
  public:
    Cat(){};
    inline string getName() const{ return name; }
    void setName(string sentName);
    ~Cat(){};
};


#endif //CLASSES_CAT_H
```

// Cat.cpp

```
#include "cat.h"

void Cat::setName(string sentName) {
  if(!sentName.empty()){
    name = sentName;
  }
}
```

Comment: _instantiation?_ or only pointer?

Comment: The pointer `tom` is not initialized.  Dereferencing `tom` results in undefined behavior (in your case a crash).  You need to initialize the object, e.g. `auto tom = std::make_unique<Cat>();`

Comment: Uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value (which will seem almost random). Now think what happens when you dereference your pointer variable `tom`.

Comment: You did not create the object of the type Cat, i.e. you try to  access the object using an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: A note about your design: It doesn't make sense to have the `getName` and `setName` functions be virtual if you have the member in the base class. Why should *all* the child-classes have to reimplement those functions?

Comment: Also note that `Animal` is not relevant for this example since you are creating an object of derived type.  In other words, if you were trying to learn how polymorphism works, this example won't get you there.  Polymorphic behavior requires a pointer/reference to the *base* class, e.g. `Animal&`, `std::unique_ptr<Animal>`, etc.

Comment: Lastly, if you want to explore polymorphism, it also doesn't make sense to have the pointer `tom` be a pointer to `Cat`, but rather a pointer to the base class. I.e. `std::unique_ptr<Animal> tom = std::make_unique<Cat>()`.

Comment: Thanks for all your helps, I am still learning c++, the big book of it's creator.
He said abstract Class are just here for 'interface' to force to implement method in other classes. So I just try it.
But maybe I did not correctly understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create its object.

```
Cat* tom = new Cat();
```

Comment: If you insist on using a raw `new`, make sure to also call `delete` to avoid memory leaks.  Better yet, use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of raw new/delete.

Comment: Hum... the compiler is not ok to do it , "allocating an object of abstract class type 'Cat'"

In fact I am trying to instanciate a Class (Which is extended of an abstract class) & access protected property of parent class

Comment: I think he writes destructor for it @0x5453

Comment: @nodeover `Cat` is considered abstract (and cannot be instantiated) because it does not implement all of the pure virtual functions from the base class `Animal`.  `Cat` is missing is the `setName` function of `Animal`.  (The version in the `Animal` interface has no parameters, but the version you have implemented in `Cat` takes a `string`, so it doesn't count.)

Comment: Thanls you that was that !! I just correct it in my header & then not use pointer & it worked!